# Bass theorem on non-affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, coherent-sheaves

A famous theorem of Bass tells that over a noetherian ring $A$, with $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ connected, every projective module of infinite type is free.

Now, consider a connected noetherian scheme $X$ and a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ that is locally free of infinite type, when do we know that it is free?

Comment: Would you consider $\oplus O_P(-1)$, infinite direct sum, over $P$ a projective space, free?

Comment: I don't know if it's free or not. In the affine case for instance, you can obtain something free by taking an infinite direct sum of a non-trivial vector bundle